# Querying Flask-SQLAlchemy through two table joins - Join not working

Tags: mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to join two tables.

Here are my tables simplified

```
class Spots(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "spots"

    geobaseid = db.Column((db.Integer), primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    spot = db.Column(db.String(50))
    url_slug = db.Column(db.String(50))
    region = db.Column(db.String(50))
    country = db.Column(db.String(50))
    chop = db.Column(db.Integer)
    small_wave = db.Column(db.Integer)
    flat = db.Column(db.Integer)
    big_wave = db.Column(db.Integer)
    west_direction = db.Column(db.Integer)
    southwest_direction = db.Column(db.Integer)
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
    url_slug = db.Column(db.String(50))

    forcast = db.relationship('Forcast_short')

class Forcast_short(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "forcast_short"

    id = db.Column((db.Integer), primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    date = db.Column(db.Date)
    geobaseid = db.Column((db.Integer), ForeignKey('spots.geobaseid'))
    spot = db.Column(db.String(50))
    region = db.Column(db.String(50))
    country = db.Column(db.String(50))
    latitude = db.Column(db.Numeric(10,8))
    longitude = db.Column(db.Numeric(10,8))
    deg = db.Column(db.Numeric(65,1))
    mps = db.Column(db.Numeric(65,1))
```

Here's my query that is not working

```
forcast_query = Forcast_short.query.join(Spots, Spots.geobaseid==Forcast_short.geobaseid).filter(Forcast_short.region == region).all()
```

What am I doing wrong?

When I run the query I only get results from Forcast_short with and without the filter.

```
<tbody>
                  <tr>{%for row in forcast_query%}
                    <td><a href="/spots/{{row.url_slug}}"> {{row.spot}} </a></td>
                    <td>{{row.mps}} </td>
                    <td>{{row.url_slug}} </td>

                  </tr>
                  {%endfor%}
                </tbody>
```

This query works in Mysql workbench.

```
select * from
(
SELECT * FROM sc_db2.forcast_short

) a
 join 
(
select * from sc_db2.spots
) b
on a.geobaseid = b.geobaseid

;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you made your models is quite confusing. In keeping with the documentation of [sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html) on **Relationship Patterns**, which I advise you to read, here is how you should set up a one to many relationship:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

This relationship places a foreign key on the child table referencing the parent. `relationship()` is then specified on the parent, as referencing a collection of items represented by the child.

**ABOUT YOUR QUERY:**

After harmonizing your models, your request should look like this:

```
forcast_query = Forcast_short.query.join(Spots, Spots.geobaseid==Forcast_short.geobaseid).filter(Forcast_short.region == region).filter(Forcast_short.date == date_1).all()
```

Comment: Hi @Tobin. Thanks for your answer. I harmonized the models as suggested but I still can't get it to work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter example which illustrates a one-to-many relationship between spots and forecasts (which I think is what you're trying to do):

```
from app import db

class Spot(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    geobaseid = db.Column(db.Integer)
    forecasts = db.relationship('Forecast', backref='spot', lazy='dynamic')


class Forecast(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    region = db.Column(db.String(50))
    spot_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('spot.id'))
```

The `db` object is set up in the `app` package initialiser, following Miguel Grinberg's [pattern](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database):

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app import models
```

Note that having set up the foreign key relationship, you don't need an explicit join to access the parent's fields from the child object - SQLAlchemy allows you to just use dot notation:

```
>>> from app import db
>>> from app.models import Spot, Forecast
>>> for spot in Spot.query.all():
...     print(spot.id, spot.geobaseid)
...
1 1
2 2
>>> for forecast in Forecast.query.all():
...     print(forecast.id, forecast.region, forecast.spot_id, forecast.spot.geobaseid)
...
1 Scotland 2 2
2 England 2 2
```